# Java/Android webrequesting

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Ive been told to use Asynctasks. but i am wondering. is it possible to make a webrequest inside a normal functions? now i need to use codeblocks like these all the time:

```
   private static HashMap<String, String> retrn = new HashMap<String,String>();
    private static class Web extends AsyncTask<String, String, Connection.Response> {
        protected Connection.Response doInBackground(String... modefiers) {
            Connection.Response res = null;
            ArrayList<String> ModList = ToAr(modefiers);
            ModList.remove(modefiers[0]);
            try {
                res = Jsoup.connect(modefiers[0])
                        .data(ModList.toArray(new String[ModList.size()]))
                        .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                        .execute();
                Document doc = res.parse();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return res;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Connection.Response result) {
            retrn.put(result.url().toString(), result.body());
        }
    }

    private static ArrayList ToAr(Object... listr){
        ArrayList Ar = new ArrayList();
        for (Object ari : listr){
            Ar.add(ari);
        }
        return Ar;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different types of solutions to run your requests. Nevertheless, keep in mind that your calls should be asynchronous, to avoid freezing the UI, and getting NetworkOnMainThreadException. So, as a raw response, no, you should not run webrequests in "normal functions". Others solutions would be

- Loaders
- RxJava
- Classical Threads

But AsyncTasks are a good and easier way to do the job. To avoid rewriting such code blocks, define separate Classes instead of innerClasses :

MyAsynctask.java :

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Connection.Response> {
//you code...
}
```

Comment: so there is no way of just using a function like: getwebcontent(String url)?

Comment: If you do something like that, without asynchronicity (just a "normal" method), you will get a NetworkOnMainThread exception. Furthermore, it is an anti-pattern. So, no.